# Adding an INNER JOIN ruins query performance due to different execution plan despite updated STATISTICS and RECOMPILE, why?

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan

In the home-page of my multi-tenant web application, Linq-to-Entities (EF6) is used to get a paged list of Calendar Events. This data is `JOIN`ed with some other tables to produce this query, below.

The tables all have composite primary keys that combine their `TenantId` with their own `IDENTITY`. I put the `IDENTITY` column first in clustered index [because `STATISTICS` only looks at the first column in an index, and I understand having the most-specific column first improves performance of get-single-row queries](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/identifying-and-solving-index-scan-problems/#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20the%20first%20column%20in,to%20statistics%20and%20the%20histogram.). (If I'm wrong about this then please let me know!).

The schema is this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events (
    EventId     int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    TenantId    int NOT NULL,
    CustomerId  int     NULL,
    EventTypeId int NOT NULL,
    LocationId  int NOT NULL,
    Etc...

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ( EventId, TenantId ),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Events_Tenants ( TenantId ) REFERENCES dbo.Tenants ( TenantId ),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Events_Customers ( CustomerId, TenantId ) REFERENCES dbo.Customers ( CustomerId, TenantId ),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Events_EventTypes ( EventTypeId, TenantId ) REFERENCES dbo.EventTypes ( EventTypeId, TenantId ),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Events_Locations ( LocationId, TenantId ) REFERENCES dbo.Locations ( LocationId, TenantId ),
)
```

The query that Linq generates is this:

<sub>(reformatted for readability, e.g. indentation, renaming Linq's `Extent1` alias to shorter aliases based on the table's name, removing redundant column aliases, and removing Linq's idiosyncratic `Project1`, these changes did not affect the execution plan)</sub>

```
SELECT
    e.(etc),
    c.(etc),
    l.(etc),
    t.(etc)
FROM
    dbo.Events AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c ON
        c.TenantId = e.TenantId
        AND
        c.CustomerId = e.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON
        l.TenantId = e.TenantId
        AND
        l.LocationId = e.LocationId
    INNER JOIN dbo.EventTypes AS t ON
        t.TenantId = e.TenantId
        AND
        t.TypeId = e.TypeId
WHERE
    e.TenantId = @tenantId

ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.EventId DESC, e.TenantId DESC )
OFFSET
    @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

- The `@tenantId` parameter is `123`.
- The `@offset` parameter is `0`.
- The `@pageSize` parameter is `50`.
- I ran the query before and after a rebuild of all indexes, as well as updating all `STATISTICS` with `sp_updatestats @resample = 'resample'`. This had no effect on the execution plan.
- I also ran them with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. This also had no effect on the execution plan.
- This query is being run on Azure SQL, btw.

---

Recently (ever since a few weeks ago) this query was running very slowly, so I got the Execution Plan for that query from SSMS:

[image]

- I have circled all execution plan nodes that pass 41,109 rows around.
- 41,109 is the number of rows in my `dbo.Events` table that correspond to the `TenantId` account I was looking at.

  - So every time I saw 41,109 in the plan I know that it was reading *all* `dbo.Events` rows - or index nodes - for that Tenant.
  - But the query has paging via `OFFSET ROWS FETCH ROWS` with an `ORDER BY` that uses the Clustered Index key columns - so it should not be reading more than 50 rows from the `dbo.Events` table!
- I've uploaded the Execution Plan to Brent Ozar's PasteThePlan website: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyc1bdkEO

I saw that the plan was reading from the `dbo.EventTypes` table first, and using the output of that read to filter rows from `dbo.Events` - but that's not my intention. My intention is for `dbo.Events` to be the "primary" table, and for it to get rows from the other tables (`dbo.Customers`, `dbo.EventTypes`, and `dbo.Locations`) based on the rows it read from `dbo.Events`.

When I removed the `INNER JOIN dbo.EventTypes AS t ON...` part of the query (and the concordant columns) and re-ran the query, the execution plan was now what I intended it to be and the query ran very fast (except without the `dbo.EventTypes` data that I still need...):

```
SELECT
    e.(etc),
    c.(etc),
    l.(etc)
FROM
    dbo.Events AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c ON
        c.TenantId = e.TenantId
        AND
        c.CustomerId = e.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON
        l.TenantId = e.TenantId
        AND
        l.LocationId = e.LocationId
WHERE
    e.TenantId = @tenantId

ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.EventId DESC, e.TenantId DESC )
OFFSET
    @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

The execution plan now shows it reading exactly 50 rows from the `dbo.Events` table. (Curiously, it also shows it reading from the `dbo.Locations` table and indexes twice - I don't understand why).

[image]

The Execution Plan window does not indicate that any indexes are missing for either query. When `dbo.EventTypes` is used in the query then the execution-plan shows the Index Seek node on `dbo.Events` is using the `TenantId` as the only seek predicate and ignoring the `EventId` predicate that would be used because of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Unfortunately none of the online resources I've found that advise improving execution plans by judicious use of indexes helped me in this cause because, as far as I know, the `dbo.Events` table has plenty of coverage by indexes (there's more than 15 indexes on the table) and none of them talked about how indexes are used by `ORDER BY`, `TOP`, and `OFFSET`. Additionally they all advised that incorrect estimated row counts (like how I see 2616 estimated but 41109 actual, or 77192 estimated but 41109 actual) would be rectified by updating `STATISTICS`, but *I did* update all statistics and that didn't help at all.

Comment: Do you possibly have the plan XML for the "fast" plan (the one that only passes 50 rows around). I wonder what makes SQL think it can safely select 50 Events rows of estimated 3213 in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-tenant systems are very prone to having problems with skewed statistics.  Both the `Events` and `Locations` table have over a million rows in them, and are using the automatic sampling rate chosen by the database engine.  You can see that in the execution plan XML, here are a couple of examples:

```xml
<StatisticsInfo 
    Database="[D0849AEA-A31D-4639-9F71-2651302E4887]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Locations]" 
    Statistics="[nci_wi_Locations_C8E94572A7BDF437552DACBCD45FE7BF]" 
    ModificationCount="981" SamplingPercent="5.79953" LastUpdate="2021-03-14T01:55:32.9" />

<StatisticsInfo 
    Database="[D0849AEA-A31D-4639-9F71-2651302E4887]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Events]" 
    Statistics="[nci_wi_Events_9AD45C8598F09E7FDFDFA2AD8792424C]" 
    ModificationCount="2113" SamplingPercent="4.56518" LastUpdate="2021-03-14T01:55:42.45" />
```

Notice that these statistics are based on sampling only ~4-5% of the rows in the table.

This is normally okay, but could be impacting your situation significantly.  I would update statistics for the indexes on both tables using the `FULLSCAN` option:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Locations
WITH FULLSCAN;
GO

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Events
WITH FULLSCAN;
GO
```

Then try re-running the query.  Hopefully the optimizer will have a better chance of estimating the join cardinality between these two tables then, and choosing the more efficient plan.

If that works, you can back down the sample rate to a lower value that still produces the good plan, and potentially "pin it" in place with the `PERSIST_SAMPLE_PERCENT`.

---

As a potential workaround: since the query works well when the join to `EventTypes` isn't present, you could remove that from your LINQ query (don't `.Include(...)` that entity, don't reference any of its properties in a `Select(...)` projection).

Then you could retrieve the 25 `EventTypes` rows needed separately, either via lazy loading (which would result in 25 additional queries, but they'd be point lookups) or by running a separate query to get them all by ID.

Getting them all by ID would be something like this:

```csharp
// "events" here is the result of your first query
var eventTypeIds = events
    .Select(e => e.EventType.Id)
    .ToList();

var eventTypes = _context.EventTypes
    .Where(et => eventTypeIds.Contains(et.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Updating statistics with fullscan did not result in an optimal execution plan under all circumstances. My application code still loads EventTypes separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try building it with the clustered index keys in the reverse order - so tenantid first.
for the inner joins add the

```
  l.TenantId = @tenantId
```

to the join criteria

change your order by from

```
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.EventId DESC, e.TenantId DESC )
```

to

```
ORDER BY e.EventId DESC, e.TenantId DESC
```

although with the reversed order you would be better served with

```
ORDER BY e.TenantId DESC, e.EventId DESC
```

if that is still acceptable
If you still get a sort consider building the PK with DESC order as well

Comment: Unfortunately the query is generated by Entity Framework / Linq which doesn't allow for the changes you're asking for - and redefining the Clustered Index for the `dbo.Events` table isn't feasible right now (and the fact the query works fine provided I don't do an `INNER JOIN dbo.EventTypes` suggests it's unnecessary.

Comment: Changing the `ORDER BY` to use the columns directly without the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function has no effect on the execution plan (with and without `RECOMPILE`).

Comment: Can you use the Force Order hint ?

Comment: No, unfortunately. With very limited exceptions I cannot make any changes to the SQL like that due to how Linq works. I can add a query-interceptor to make some changes but that's a last-resort option. Using a force-order hint shouldn't be necessary though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LINQ is notorious for generating sub-par (and even terrible) queries in regards to performance for even some of the simplest code (such as a join between two entities, or a contains search on a single entity, etc). This is evident even in your query by the fact it added a meaningless `ROW_NUMBER()` function call in your `ORDER BY` clause, when it can just `ORDER BY` the fields it's calling out inside the `ROW_NUMBER()` function directly themselves.

That being said, I don't necessarily know if LINQ is your actual issue here yet though. If you take the first generated query (inclusive of your join to `EventTypes`), and run it directly in **SSMS** with hard-coded values instead of parameters, how is the performance? If it's good then you could be experiencing a **parameter sniffing** issue with the parameterized query sent to the server from LINQ. This in turn could be causing a **cardinality estimate** issue, which may be what your first **execution plan** screenshot is even showing, but it's hard to confirm without the **actual execution plan** in front of us. Could you please upload it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan)? There's a lot of information in the **actual execution plan** that's not shown in a screenshot.

Also sidenote, clauses like `TOP` and `OFFSET` generally don't reduce your dataset early on, rather they're applied later on in the order of operations. This is because predicate filtering (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses) are typically used to filter the data down first since they're specific to how to filter the data (as opposed to `TOP` and `OFFSET` being generic) and call out fields that potentially are indexed, so this influences the order of operations in a query. The SQL Engine is able to make use of indexes early on in the set of operations it performs (because indexes store the data in logical data structure of a **B-Tree** which is very efficient for searching), after that then it can then apply generic reduction to the dataset vis `TOP`, `OFFSET`, etc. So it's generally most optimal to reduce your data via predicates, or at least ensure your predicates are optimally indexed and used for efficient index usage by the SQL Engine when it goes to pull the data.

Comment: Regarding the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` - I did some research on that last week and I found out that that the Entity Framework dev-team is confident that using `ROW_NUMBER()` for stable-sorts is reliable _and performant_ so they made it the default in an update to EF6 in 2019 (see https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/commit/8caee28305de907a23f766586e4a358299c3633c#diff-2348f5cea0279a4ef52357a219ff8be3d9a156e9ac4921e34bcf4f3dfb8f3269 ) and are even considering removing the `UseRowNumberOrderingInOffsetQueries` option entirely (so it will _always_ use `ROW_NUMBER()`). It made no difference to my own query.

Comment: @Dai I didn't say `ROW_NUMBER()` was your issue, just pointing out an example of how LINQ can make decisions that don't make sense. That's fine if they want to default to it, but there's literally no reason in doing it vs using the fields inside of it. I bet unfortunately the EF Team doesn't have the experience to realize that the sort is exactly the same in both cases, and goes to show they shouldn't code *hard and fast* rules. Please see the in my answer about testing for **parameter sniffing** issues and uploading your **execution plan** so we can check for **cardinality estimate** issues.

Comment: @Dai Note I read through the Git comments they made in your link, and it's exactly the case I thought. Essentially when you `ORDER BY` fields in SQL (in any context), if the combination of fields aren't unique then you end up with a semi-random ordering that occurs between executions of that query, that are nondeterministic. For example if you have a table of `Cars` with the fields `Manufacturer` and `Model` (so the data in the table could be `Nissan` `Altima`, and `Nissan` `Maxima`) if you `ORDER BY` just the `Manufacturer` field, there's an equal probability the results will order the...

Comment: rows with the `Nissan Maxima` first then the `Nissan Altima` or the `Nissan Altima` first then the `Nissan Maxima`, it's semi-random. The same is true even when (and especially when) using `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate unique IDs `OVER` the ordering of non-unique sets of fields, such as in my example with the `Manufacturer` field. In one execution the `ROE_NUMBER()` generated for the `Nissan Maxima` will be 1 and 2 will be generated for the `Nissan Altima` and in another execution the numbers will be reversed and the `Nissan Altima` will be assigned 1 while the `Nissan Maxima` will be assigned...

Comment: ...2, leading to random sorting still even with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. The developer who wrote that Git comment probably ended up *masking* the issue enough to not replicate it during his testing, but it still exists and the sorting is still non-deterministic, and users will experience different result sets due to it when using EF.

Comment: Interesting - I was aware of the unstable-sort comment, but I didn't really understand why it would be a problem. I suggest you file a bug report against them as the same "feature" is in EF Core too...

Comment: Here is my execution plan btw: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyc1bdkEO

Comment: @Dai Good point, I probably will inform them. I really like Microsoft personally, been working solely in their tech stack my entire career, and they usually crush it good, but it saddens me to see when they drop the ball on something like that. Anyways thanks for posting your **execution plan**, you should add it to your original post too so more users see it and can possibly help. I'll take a look but have to run into work soon so might not get a chance to respond right away, but I'll try.

Comment: @J.D. If you're able to figure this out I'd love to keep you on retainer for other query performance issues in future :D

Comment: @Dai Sorry, literally right after I last replied I got pulled into a work fire, so just got a chance to review your **execution plan** a little closer. It does look like there's some **cardinality estimate** issues such as with the **index seek** operation that is occuring on the `Foo1.dbo.Customer` entity. I'll have to drill in deeper tomorrow when I'm in front of computer (writing this from my phone before bed) but that *may* be your issue. Have you tried running a non-parameterized (hard-coded values in place of the parameters) version of the first LINQ generated query in **SSMS**?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these indexes or equivalents:

```
CREATE INDEX IX1 ON EventTypes ( TenantId, EventypeId)
CREATE INDEX IX2 ON Locations (Tenantid, LocationId)
```

You say you have clustered indexes, where the columns are the other way around. Yet from the execution plan it seems SQL Server favors indexes where TenantId is the first key column.

I would also try changing all the inner joins to left joins. At least as experiment. It doesn't seem any of the tables affect the number of rows returned except Events.

From my perspective SQL Server is very confused here. The join between Events and Locations produces 41k rows where SQL Server expects 41. Three orders of magnitude diference. And this error propagates thorough the whole plan.